# ITHit credentials issue in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ithit-ajax-file-browser

Currently we use **ITHit Webdav Ajax Library** to develop a new feature of our product. We intend to provide a link in web browser allowing user to open a document inside our webdav server.

In Windows it runs well but in Ubuntu, we face a problem with credentials. The **ITHit** applet always ask: 1.**Webdav**  credentials 2.**Sudo** credentials.

If I log in the **os** by user in **sudo** group (suppose that is **USER1**), I can open/edit the document well when providing id/password of **USER1** in step2. But if I log in by the user that does not belong to **sudo** group(suppose that is **USER2**), then in step2 I enter id/password of **USER2**, I can not open/edit the document. The exception I always see is: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not mount webdav server, please verify provided credentials**. I even grant permission for running **mount** & **mount.davfs** for **USER2** but still get the same error.(Notice that with these permission, I log in as **USER2** and can mount the webdav folder to a local folder manually successfully!)

I test **www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser** and face the same issue.

The question here is, why do you need the **sudo** credentials? As I understand, you need to create a local folder and mount it with the webdav folder containing the document that user wants to open. With that action, only **mount** or **mount.davfs** is enough. It is too risk to provide the sudo credentials to an applet.
WDYT?

Comment: We have fixed this issue and will soon publish the update. The sudo credentials will be requested only in case a call without sudo failed.

Answer (score 0):

From our experience to successfully mount and use WebDAV on Ubuntu you will need davfs2, not davfs. Unfortunately davfs2 requires sudo credentials.

Note that if you have KDE installed it would not ask for sudo credentials.

Comment: Hi, as I understand, the **davfs2** is the package we need to install, and **mount.davfs** is the command of **davfs2** package.

Before installing **davfs2**, I can not run **mount.davfs**. After installing **davfs2**, I can run the command **mount.davfs** in my console. 

Also, after granting permission to run **mount.davfs2** for **USER2** and add him to **davfs2** group, **USER2** can mount and user WebDAV on Ubuntu, even he does not belong to **sudo** group.

So, **sudo** is not mandatory here in Ubuntu (I use GNOME but KDE)